# How a command which is meant to output indefinitely, when piped to another command that waits for a certain amount of input, knows when to terminate?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, subshell

I am baffled by how piping in bash works.
Take a random string generator, for example:

```
tr -dc 'A-Z0-9' </dev/urandom
```

spawned `tr` process that reads from */dev/urandom* indefinitely, as far as */dev/urandom* providing with output, until something interrupt it.
Now take this:

```
tr -dc 'A-Z0-9' </dev/urandom | fold -w 8 | head -n 1
```

Immediately outputs the first line of that seemingly indefinite output of uppercase alphanumeric characters folded in 8 symbols per line. That is generated 8 random uppercase alphanumeric characters.
I sort of have the intuition from the `head` standpoint: it waits for the first line and it's the only thing it waits for from its *stdin*.

`man bash` says:

> Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in a subshell).

How exactly `head` tells `fold` and it tells `tr` that that's enough? Does `fold` send a termination signal to the `tr` process? Or is it some more complicated behavior, like say `head`'s */dev/stdin* points to the same stream as `fold`'s */dev/stdout*, and when `head` closes the stream, `fold` gets a termination signal? What's happens to those subshells when they stack is such pipeline?

And a side question: how should I write my bash scripts so that they work properly when stacked in a pipeline?

Comment: The "side" question of properly stacking pipelines probably deserves its own separate question.

Comment: See, for example, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/513657/understanding-piped-commands-in-unix-linux/513662#513662 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29964/are-linux-utilities-smart-when-running-piped-commands/29976#29976 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243350/why-does-using-yes-on-bash-pipelines-not-cause-infinite-loops/243352#243352 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84813/what-makes-a-unix-process-die-with-broken-pipe/84828#84828

Comment: tl;dr. Head exits, so its stdin is closed. Fold writes to stdout, gets a SIGPIPE, doesn't catch it, gets killed. Rinse and repeat.